# How to easily peel fresh walnuts?

Tags: nuts

Due to allergies the thin skin on the walnut itself needs to be removed. The walnuts itself are not dried yet and it is possible to remove it by hand in a time consuming effort. Is there an easy way to do that? Bonus if that method works as well on dried ones.

Answer (score 2):

Below methods work on dried and fresh walnuts:

- put walnuts in bowl and pour boiling water, after 15 minutes pour out the water. skin should be easily removes with nails or small knife
- put nuts on a baking tray, put in oven warmed up to 200C (400F) for 15 minutes. When walnuts will cool off you can rub the skin out in your hand (if you have allergy you may use gloves)

Comment: The first one doesn't seem to be less work than doing it without the water. The second won't even work with fresh walnuts.